# Application or object defined error Runtime error 1004

Tags: vba

I have created the following code to extract information from an excel table. But I am getting an error exactly at the if statement. I have even tried executing the code from a module and even from the worksheet level. I have read about this issue and it seems that selecting the sheet seems to be the main problem, but I have also tried but in vain I can't seem to find a solution. It would be really great if someone could help me with this. Thank you in advance.

```
Sub test()
Dim row As Double, col As Double, inc As Double
row = 2
col = 2
inc = 20
'Sheets("sche").Range("a1").Select
For row = 2 To 15
For col = 2 To 52
If (Cells(r, c).Font.Bold Or Left(Cells(r, c).Value, 2) = "BP") Then 'Error is happening here
       Sheets("sche").Cells(inc, 2).Value = Sheets("sche").Cells(r, c).Value
 inc = inc + 1
GoTo zone
Else: GoTo zone
End If
zone:
Next col
Next row
End sub
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, as a side note in addition to my answer below, [this ruberduck blog entry about Clean VBA Code pt.2: Avoiding implicit code](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/10/25/clean-vba-code-pt-2-avoiding-implicit-code) is a nice easy way to learn about how to write *explicit* references in your code - At least the fist section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared `row` and `col` as variables but are using `r` and `c` in your `If...Then` block.

A prime example of why you should add [`Option Explicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) at the top of every module to prevent typo's and using undeclared variables.

I've adjusted your code and tested it OK:

***Note:** I removed the `Else` condition and `GoTo Zone` as they were redundant in your code (at least in the example you provided). Also although not a cause of your error it's not necesarry to encapsulate your entire `If...Then` condition in parentheses.*

```
Sub test()
    Dim row As Double, col As Double, inc As Double
    row = 2
    col = 2
    inc = 20
    'Sheets("sche").Range("a1").Select
    For row = 2 To 15
        For col = 2 To 52
            If Cells(row, col).Font.Bold Or Left(Cells(row, col).Value, 2) = "BP" Then 'Error is happening here
                Sheets("sche").Cells(inc, 2).Value = Sheets("sche").Cells(row, col).Value
                inc = inc + 1
            End If
        Next col
    Next row
End Sub
```

I've changed this:

```
            If Cells(r, c).Font.Bold Or Left(Cells(r, c).Value, 2) = "BP" Then 'Error is happening here
                Sheets("sche").Cells(inc, 2).Value = Sheets("sche").Cells(r, c).Value
```

To this:

```
            If Cells(row, col).Font.Bold Or Left(Cells(row, col).Value, 2) = "BP" Then 'Error is happening here
                Sheets("sche").Cells(inc, 2).Value = Sheets("sche").Cells(row, col).Value
```

---

Furthermore, it's good practice to *expicitly* reference your objects.

This is because, for example, the *implicit* reference for the [`Cells()` property is the Active Worksheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells):

> *Using this property without an object qualifier returns a Range object that represents all the cells on the active worksheet.*

This can cause unexpected results if for example, you run your code whilst a different sheet than desired is active or a user changes worksheets during the codes execution.

It would be better to write the code like:

```
If Sheets("sche").Cells(row, col).Font.Bold Or Left(Sheets("sche").Cells(row, col).Value, 2) = "BP" Then
```

The `With` statement can come in handy to shorten the written code when making many references to the same objects, like workbooks, worksheets and/or Ranges etc. You can read about it [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement).